# libopenscenegraph80 error on ubuntu trusty partial upgrade

Tags: 14.04, partial-upgrade

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and today it asked to do a partial upgrade which I did. It came up with and error:

[image]

I tried to install the package but the problem still occurs. The output to command

```
sudo apt-get install libopenscenegraph80
```

is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libopenscenegraph80
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 52 not to upgrade.
```

There does not seem to be any package information for libopenscenegraph80 under trusty package system.The latest version is for saucy. Is this an error that I can avoid or ignore without major consequences?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install libopenscenegraph80` in the terminal and include any errors you may encounter here.

Comment: Added to the main section above. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `libopenscenegraph80` package is set hold. Try the below commands to unhold and install the above mentioned package.

```
sudo apt-mark unhold libopenscenegraph80
sudo apt-get install libopenscenegraph80
```

Comment: It returns `libopenscenegraph80 was already not hold.` and error stays the same.